# Taking input from cin and storing it in a char variable

Tags: c++, char

I'm taking input using cin and storing it into a char variable. My question is if there is any input that could cause `cin.fail()` to return true.

I know that trying to store input such as `"foo"` into an int variable will fail, but is there any case in which this is possible with a char variable?

Comment: Did you tried special keys and commands? in example, did you tried to terminate the program with `Cmd+X` / `Ctrl+C` or with any command that close the program inside terminal? A char is usually 1 byte, meaning you can give only all possible values from 0 to 255 (on windows you do `Alt+Num` where num is numeric pad number to enter an ascii value). Also tried multibyte only characters (like `Alt+1234`)? you could try "newline", "end of file character" etc.

Comment: Ask yourself: What would happen if, during the read attempt, someone rips the USB stick with the file you're reading from out of the computer?

Comment: Are you using `cin >> c` or `c = cin.get()`?

Comment: `Crtl+Z` will cause `fail()` to be true on windows

Comment: I'm using cin >> var. And @DevSolar, this isn't a relevant issue.

Comment: @DarioOO cin.fail() doesn't return true for any of those from what I can tell. I believe that it just reads the first byte as its character and doesn't care about the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overloads for `operator>>` which take a `char` follow the normal behavior of a *formatted input function*, that is they call `rdbuf()->sbumpc()` or `rdbuf()->sgetc()` to perform the extraction. Naturally, if `eof` is encountered, then `eofbit` is set. If one of the functions throw an exception, then `badbit` is set. If either of these are set, then `failbit` is set. There's no evidence to indicate that the operation would fail otherwise. (This is covered under section [istream] in the C++11 draft standard.) For other types, like `int`, `do_get()` is used to convert the character (similar to `scanf`). Of course, the conversion can fail, but no conversion is needed if the input is already a `char`.

Now the comments are misleading. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would kill the application in Linux. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> would send a character that signals EOF on some operating systems.

You can even use an emoji and it would work:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char c;
    if (std::cin >> c)
        std::cout << "Huzzah!";
}
```

With input  outputs "Huzzah!" as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess not because a char variable with just take only the first character from the given input, no matter how long the input or of what type it is (int,long,double..)

Answer (score 0):

No, failbit is only set if there's a logical error reading the input stream, AKA, someone rips out the USB flashdrive containing the file from which you're reading. ;)